# CLT with inconsistent estimator

Tags: self-study, least-squares, convergence, central-limit-theorem, consistency

So I have the OLS estimator that is inconsistent due to the mean independence assumption being violated.  I'm asked whether $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)$ converges when the sample size $n$ goes to infinity.

If the beta estimator had been consistent, I could have used the CLT. Is it still possible to use it when beta is inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. An immediate way to see this is to write $\widehat \beta = \beta + O_p(n^{-1/2})$ whereas convergence in probability is equivalent to $\widehat \beta = \beta + o_p(1)$. But I'll outline a more rigorous argument since it seems like you may not be comfortable with this type of argument (it sort of begs the question if you don't know why $\sqrt n$ convergence implies convergence in probability to begin with).

Suppose $\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta)$ converges in distribution to any random variable $Z$ which is finite almost surely. Let $K$ be a continuity point of the cdf $F_Z$ chosen so that $\Pr(Z > K) < \delta$ for some small $\delta$. Then:
$$
\Pr(\widehat \beta - \beta > \epsilon)
=
\Pr(\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta) > \sqrt n \epsilon)
\le
\Pr(\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta) > K)
$$
provided that $n$ is sufficiently large. It follows that
$$
\limsup \Pr(\widehat \beta - \beta > \epsilon) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr(\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta) > K) < \delta.
$$
But this holds for arbitrary $\delta$, so we must have $\Pr(\widehat\beta - \beta > \epsilon) \to 0$. Repeat this argument for $\Pr(\widehat \beta - \beta < -\epsilon)$ to get that $\Pr(|\widehat \beta - \beta| > \epsilon) \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm not really comfortable with the topic. Assuming that I got it right, finally it means that $\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta)$ converges in probability, given that $\Pr(|\widehat \beta - \beta| > \epsilon) \to 0$ ? 
Thanks!

Comment: @LFG The result is that $\sqrt n (\widehat \beta - \beta)$ converging in distribution to anything implies that $\widehat\beta$ converges in probability to $\beta$. By contrapositive, this implies that your CLT cannot hold for inconsistent estimates (as the CLT implies consistency).